# Saxon-CE progressbar while processing, rendering blocked?

Tags: jquery, xml, twitter-bootstrap, xslt, saxon

I'm using Saxon-CE to transform an XML file. I want to set a progressbar while the XSLT Processor is running. But somehow it seems that the view is blocked. I can't even set a button's value to "Transforming...". The console.log tells me that the html value of the button changed, but somehow it's not rendering.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function XSLT(selected){
    $('#transform-button').html('Transforming ...');
    console.log($('#transform-button').html());
    var xsltData = Saxon.requestXML("XSLT.xsl");
    var xmlData = Saxon.parseXML("XML.xml");
    var xsltProcessor = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsltData);
    for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        var percentage = 100 / selected.length * i;
        xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "selected", selected[i]);
        var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlFile);
        var resdoc = xsltProcessor.getResultDocuments();
        Progress(Math.round(percentage));
    }
}
```

I'm using the Bootstrap's "progress-bar progress-bar-striped active".

```
function Progress(val) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', val + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', val);
    $('.progress-bar').text(val + '%');

}
```

Can anyone help me to make this work? My transformation takes a long time so I have to make a progressbar or a spinner or something.  But even a spinner can't be started in my function XSLT.

Comment: Javascript normally runs single threaded in the browsers GUI thread which means that longer computations block the GUI. Whether it is possible to run Saxon CE from WebWorkers I am not sure, you might need to try to break up your code into chunks put into functions where you then use `setTimeout` to call the next chunk as that way the Javascript engine yields processing back to the browser in between computations. You seem to be using JQuery or some other library, so you might want to tag your question to find help on that, as I think the problem and solution is in client-side scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came along this solution :

```
var onSaxonLoad = function() {
    var xsl = Saxon.requestXML("toc.xsl");
    var xml = Saxon.requestXML("toc.xml");
    var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsl);
    proc.setSuccess(function(){
        removeProgressBar();            
    });

    setProgressBar(); 
    proc.updateHTMLDocument(xml);            
}

function setProgressBar(){
  //static for now in body
}

function removeProgressBar(){
  $('#page_load_progress').remove();
}
```

I am using full-length progress bar so I don't need to  change its width. Instead I update progress bar content to set text from xslt using `eval`ed event e.g

```
function updateStatus(status){
  $('#progress_status').html(status +' loading... ');
}
```

From within xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="progress_status"   select="concat('updateStatus(&quot;',string($name),'&quot;)')"/>
<ixsl:set-property name="dummy"  select="ixsl:eval($progress_status)"/>
```

progress snippet

```
<div id="page_load_progress" class="modal show" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-backdrop  in" style="height:100%"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog text-center">
        <div class="modal-content btn active" style="width: 40%">
            <div class="modal-body ">
                <progress style="width:100%;" ></progress>
                <div id="progress_status" class="text-info" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, Saxon.parseXML() expects the actual lexical XML content as its argument - not a URI. I'm not sure why you aren't using requestXML() here.

Generally the way I have done this is to break up the transformation into smaller pieces by using ixsl:schedule-action() with a wait of 0 (or something very small). This gives other things a chance to execute, and you could update a progress bar at this point.